# How do I retrieve a list stored in a cookie on another static html page?

Tags: jquery, json, cookies

I have trying to figure out how cookies work. I have this piece of code where I want to stringify a list and assigning it to a cookie.

```
<script src = "js/jquery.cookie.js" type ="application/javascript">
$.cookie('cookie_name', JSON.stringify(mynewthingslist));
</script>
```

My list is getting values dynamically by .getJSON which will append it to the list.

```
<ol id = "mynewthingslist" >
                    </ol>
```

Then I want to retrieve the values contained in that cookie and view it in another static html page. I am now parsing it using JSON and I want to display it in a favourites list.

```
<script src = "js/jquery.cookie.js" type ="application/javascript">
var list = JSON.parse($.cookie('cookie_name'));
$("#favouriteslist").append("<ul></ul>");
for(var i in list) {
    var li = "<li>";
    $("ol").append(li.concat(arr[i]))
    </script>
```

How do I do that ?